# Compare Values in an array and get the nearest one using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have an array e.g

```
[4, 9, 12, 18, 29]
```

I want to compare all the values and decide which are the closest to each other. Like in this case it will be 9 and 12.
It will be very helpful if someone can tell me how to do it.

Comment: sort all the values in the array.Then in a while loop we can take diff between adjacent values.Pair with lowest diff will be the ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
var i,j;
var first,second;
var min_diff = arr[1] - arr[0];
for (i = 2 ; i != arr.length ; i++) {
    min_diff = Math.min(min_diff, arr[i]-arr[i-1]);
}

for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    for(j=1; j<arr.length; j++){
        temp = arr[j] - arr[i];
        if(temp == min_diff){
            first = arr[i];  // first element
            second = arr[j]; // second element
        }
    }
}
```